# How to change RStudio temporary folder where RStudio temporarily downloads packages?

Tags: rstudio

1) I don't need change library folder
.libPaths()
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library"

(This is a library both for R and for RStudio, and it suits me!)

2) I don't need change Rstudio work directory!

3) I want only change folder, where Rstudio temporarily writes download packages.

I created so folder:

C:/tempR

But I don't know how to tell Rstudio download packages into it

Comment: ?install.packages and check out the `destdir` parameter.  The documentation is your friend.

Comment: Oh, Thanks, Dason! It workes: 

install.packages ("package_name", destdir = "D:/tempR")

P.S. it would be nice if I could specify once, not every time

Comment: Make your own function for it?  `myfun <- function(...){install.packages(..., destdir = "D:/tempR")}`

Comment: Rstudio reaction to this function is:       WARNING MESSAGE: IN DIR.CREATE(TEMPPATH, RECURSIVE = TRUE) : CANNOT CREATE DIR 'C:\USERS\?????????????', REASON 'INVALID ARGUMENT'
////// RStudio does not understand that I'm creating D:/tempR (as a temporary folder for download packages) just because I do not want C:\Users\?????????????

Comment: P.S. I think, somewhere in RStudio settings, there should be an opportunity to change the folder where the packages are downloaded.